# Passing data beetween two angular-formly forms

Tags: angular-formly

I'm trying to check model of form1 from form2. How can I get it working?
Here's jsbin describing what I would like to have.
http://jsbin.com/kuluhataka/edit?js,output

Comment: Post relevant code here as well, and any specific problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously recommend against doing what you're trying to do. Types should only be for fields, not for forms. Use angular for what it's good at and formly for what it's good at.

One other thing that's important to note is that `expressionProperties` only run when the form's given model is changed. This is why yours wasn't running when you changed the value of the other field (because they have different model attributes).

Here's a working solution: http://jsbin.com/resafa/1/edit?html,js,output

JavaScript

```
vm.model = {
  form1: {},
  form2: {}
};
vm.fields1 = [
  {
    key:'field1',
    model: 'model.form1',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'form1.Input',
      placeholder: 'Formly is terrific!'
    }
  },
  {
    key:'field1',
    model: 'model.form2',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'form2.Input',
      placeholder: 'Formly is terrific!'
    },
    expressionProperties: {
      'templateOptions.disabled': '!options.data.originalModel.form1.field1',
    },
    // https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/pull/443
    // when that ^ PR gets merged and released, then you don't have to do this step
    // and you can reference it as `options.originalModel` rather than `options.data.originalModel`
    // This should happen in the next day or so
    data: {
      originalModel: vm.model
    }
  }
];
```

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" name="vm.form" novalidate>
  <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields1" options="vm.options" form="vm.form">            
  </formly-form>
  <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields2" options="vm.options" form="vm.form">
  </formly-form>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This is what I needed.
Look at this example http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/nested-formly-forms - you are using here types for fields, thats why i was doing it like this ;-)